# Can I not add metadata to documents loaded using Chroma.from_documents()

Tags: python-3.x, large-language-model, py-langchain, chromadb

I wanted to add additional metadata to the documents being embedded and loaded into Chroma.
I'm unable to find a way to add metadata to documents loaded using
`Chroma.from_documents(documents, embeddings)`
For example, imagine I have a text file having details of a particular disease, I wanted to add species as a metadata that is a list of all species it affects.

As a round-about way I loaded it in a chromadb collection by adding required metadata and persisted it

```
client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path="chromaDB")

collection = client.get_or_create_collection(name="test",
                                             embedding_function=openai_ef,
                                             metadata={"hnsw:space": "cosine"})
```

```
collection.add(
     documents=documents,
     ids=ids,
     metadatas=metadata
)
```

This was the result,

```
collection.get(include=['embeddings','metadatas'])
```

Output:

> {'ids': ['id0',
> 'id1',
> 'embeddings': [[-0.014580891467630863,
> 0.0003901976451743394,
> 0.00793908629566431,
> -0.027648288756608963,
> -0.009689063765108585,
> 0.010222840122878551,
> -0.00946609303355217,
> -0.002771923551335931,
> -0.04675614833831787,
> -0.02056729979813099,
> 0.014364678412675858,
> ...
> {'species': 'XYZ', 'source': 'Flu.txt'},
> {'species': 'ABC', 'source': 'Common_cold.txt'}],
> 'documents': None,
> 'uris': None,
> 'data': None}

Now I tried loading it from the directory persisted in the disk using `Chroma.from_documents()`

```
db = Chroma(persist_directory="chromaDB", embedding_function=embeddings)
```

But I don't see anything loaded. `db.get()` results in this,

```
db.get(include=['metadatas'])
```

Output:

> {'ids': [],
> 'embeddings': None,
> 'metadatas': [],
> 'documents': None,
> 'uris': None,
> 'data': None}

Please help. Need to load metadata to the files being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself. Missed to post it.
I was stupid and haven't mentioned the collection name while loading.

Instead of doing this,

`db = Chroma(persist_directory="chromaDB", embedding_function=embeddings)`

Do this,

`db = Chroma(persist_directory="chromaDB", embedding_function=embeddings, collection_name = 'your_collection_name')`

In my case, the collection name is ***'test'***.
Works fine